# Checking to see if on last option of dropdown in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a program that is going to keep clicking on the `listingnextbtn` button until it reaches the last page, the website design makes this tricky so the only way I can do it is by detected that it is on the last option of the page number list dropdown.

```
<div id="pgn-nav" class="pgn-nav">
    <a id="listingNextBtn" class="btn blue disabled" role="button" href="#"><span class="btn-txt bg-grey">Prev</span></a>
    <select id="listingPageNumber" class="pageNumber">
        <option value="1">1 - 150</option><option value="2">151 - 300</option><option value="3">301 - 450</option><option value="4">451 - 600</option><option value="5">601 - 750</option><option value="6">751 - 900</option><option value="7">901 - 916</option>
    </select>
    <a id="listingNextBtn" class="btn blue" role="button" href="#"><span class="btn-txt bg-grey">Next</span></a>
</div>
```

I just have no idea how to check to see if its on the last option, everything else is pretty straightforward.

EDIT:
The code I have for this portion so far.

```
try:
    barack = soup.find(id='listingPageNumber')
    #if barack == last object
    print('Reached last dropdown object)
    #do something, like click button
except:
    print('Not at the end of listpage yet')
```

Comment: And WHY it's so *tricky*? Show your code and describe the issue in more details

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I have looked around and haven't seen anyone else have a similar issue, so I don't really have anything to go off of, nor do I know if what I am asking is even possible. I only have a try except statement for this part of my program because I really don't know how to go forward to get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not clear, so the code might not fit it well

You can try to do as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# Define Select object
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("listingPageNumber"))
# Get currently selected option
current = select.all_selected_options[0].text
# Get last option in the list of available options
last = [option.text for option in select.options][-1]

# Check if current option is the last option
if current == last:
    print("Last option is selected")
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I explained it so poorly but this is what I needed.